# How to show result only when all form fields are filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, calculator

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".input").bind("change keyup", function(){
            var val1 = +$(".value1").val();
            var val2 = +$(".value2").val();
            var val3 = +$(".value3").val();
            var val4 = +$(".value4").val();
            $("#result").val(val1+val2+val3+val4);
     });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <select class="input value1">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <select class="input value2">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <select class="input value3">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="input value4">
  <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="result">
</body>
</html>
```

I want to show the result only when all fields are filled or selected. Additionally, in a disabled text field I want to print a message like 'You must check every field' when some field isn't filled. How to modify this code to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you using classes to identify individual controls?  This is the purpose of the "id" attribute.

Comment: It's only an example. I know it's better to use id's instead of classes in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".input").bind("change keyup", function(){
        var val1 = +$(".value1").val();
        var val2 = +$(".value2").val();
        var val3 = +$(".value3").val();
        var val4 = +$(".value4").val();

        if(parseFloat(val1) > 0 && parseFloat(val2) > 0 && parseFloat(val3) > 0 && parseFloat(val4) > 0) {
           $("#result").val(val1+val2+val3+val4);
        }
        else {
           $("#result").val('You must check every field');
        }              
   });
});
```